# How can I create a graphic like illustration of an actual design in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, filter, graphic-styles

Okay, let me elaborate on the use case a little. I have a home based business that creates handcrafted products using cloth. Now I want a catalog of the designs of the cloth materials that I have in my inventory. I can work my way around by taking actual photographs of the cloth material and handing it over to the client. But this doesn't seem too professional to me, as the images look like they are crumpled and taken on a cell phone camera. How can I provide a more refined filter and make it look more graphical rather than an actual photograph.

Comment: Can you post an image please?  I don't know if it's possible to tell you anything without some visual reference - and as you know, graphic design is all about visuals

Comment: Take a couple of photos and put them to some cloud for us to see. Or insert one to your question. Do the photographing  under the sky, but in a shadow. Include a piece of neutral grey material into a corner of the same photos, not separately. Use white paper, if there's nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who shops cloth from time to time, I would advise against using anything illustrated.

The look and feel of a piece of cloth is very important, one piece of patterned cotton isn't the other. It's going to be very hard to put a realistic representation of the fabric in your catalog through illustration. Personally, I wouldn't shop from a catalog with computer generated preview images, because there is just no way of telling what you're actually getting. It might also suggest you are trying to hide the 'real' photos, suggesting that the quality isn't all that.

I would suggest to either hire someone to take photographs of your cloth, or invest in making your own. You can get a long way with even 50 bucks and either make or buy yourself a small lightbox to shoot photos in. If you have a modern smartphone with decent camera, a lightbox can get you a long way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scanner rather than a camera.

You could hire a professional photographer to take photos - resulting in high quality digital images, rather than "cell phone photos".

You could recreate patterns in software to create digital representations. How you accomplish this *greatly* depends upon the pattern itself and may or may not take considerable time and/or skill. Without some sample images, it is impossible to provide any real direction with this method.